# c++ Firebase Auth error

Tags: c++, firebase, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to log in using the Auth function of Firebase SDK in C ++ project.
However, LNK 2019 Error floats when # import "firebase / auth.h".
Even if Firebase is added to library in Visual Studio, Error will float.
The same Error floats even if all the header of firebase is imported.
Please help me.

ps. I used Google's translation.

Comment: Show us your efforts

Comment: I attempted to use a sample supported by firebase (https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample).

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase C++ SDK is base on the Andorid or IOS device.

***Setup for iOS***

**Prerequisites**

Xcode 8.0 or later.

For Cloud Messaging:

A physical iOS device

APNs certificate with Push Notifications enabled

***Setup for Android***

**Prerequisites**

Android NDK version 10d or later.

Android SDK.

please check the online document.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup